# How to check if entered time is between start time and end time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to construct an API in which, current time will be taken(ie 7:30 p.m.) and it will be compared with starting time(i.e. 6:00 a.m) and closing time (i.e 8:00 p.m.). If the time falls between these two limits, positive response will be given in the output.

Is there any Date function through which I can do this. If not what is the effective method to check hours and minutes to compare these limits?

Comment: 1) get three `Date` objects 2) compare them using the standard relational operators `<`, `>` etc?

Comment: can I initialize start timing object as new Date('7:30 p.m') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string time representations to number and compare those;
Try this;

```js
function timeToNumber(timeString) {
  var t = timeString.split(" ");

  var offset = 0;

  if (t[1] == "PM") {
    offset = 12;
  }

  var hm = t[0].split(":");

  var hours = Number(hm[0]) + offset;

  return hours * 100 + Number(hm[1]);
}

function timeCompare(min, max, ref) {
  return (timeToNumber(min) <= timeToNumber(ref)) && (timeToNumber(ref) <= timeToNumber(max));
}

var rangeMin = "6:00 AM";
var rangeMax = "8:00 PM";
var reference = "7:30 PM"



console.log(timeCompare(rangeMin, rangeMax, reference))
```

Note; this only works if there is no day change between your time range limits. should you compare your reference with such ranges, use full datetime not just the time.

Comment: You might wish to use  a more suitable example. In safari, `new Date("11-01-2000")` returns an invalid date so the above returns false.

Comment: I leave that part to the original poster. timeCheck function will work regardless of the browser if the Date objects provided correctly

Comment: Here, I don't want to compare date-moth-year. I want to compare h:mm: format (i.e compare 7:00 with 6:00 and 12:24),so can you suggest how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var today = new Date().getHours();
if (today >= 6 && today <= 20) {
   alert('good time');
} else {
    alert('bad time')
}
```

This code is not working for 20:05 as @RobG mentioned so I change the compare time in Minutes. Thanks @RobG.

```js
var totalMinutes = new Date().getHours() * 60 + new Date().getMinutes();
if (totalMinutes >= 360 && totalMinutes <= 1200) {
   alert('good time');
} else {
    alert('bad time')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RobG, just changed the code

Answer (score 1):

there is a module [moment](https://momentjs.com/) for date and time manipulation. If you want to find the difference between two times, here you go!

```
var moment = require('moment');

var startTime = moment(new Date());
var endTime   = moment(new Date());

var timeDiff  = endTime.diff(startTime,"ms"); //in mili-seconds
var timeDiff  = endTime.diff(startTime,"s"); //in seconds
var timeDiff  = endTime.diff(startTime,"h"); //in hour
```

and many more uses you can find in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches that you can try. One is to use a Date by providing the start and end times, e.g.

```js
/* Return true if date is between startTime and endTime, otherwise false. 
** @param {string} startTime - in format HH:mm
** @param {string} endTime - in format HH:mm
** @param {Date} date - date to compare, default is now
** @returns {boolean}
*/
function inTime(startTime, endTime, date) {
  function toMins(v) {
    v = v.split(':');
    return v[0]*60 + +v[1];
  }
  var now = new Date();
  startTime = new Date(+now).setHours(0, toMins(startTime), 0, 0); 
  endTime = new Date(+now).setHours(0, toMins(endTime), 0, 0); 

  return now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
}

console.log('Is it between 6am and 8pm? ' + inTime('6:00','20:00'));
```

Another is to just use the minutes part of a date:

```js
/* Return true if date is between startTime and endTime, otherwise false. 
 ** @param {string} startTime - in format HH:mm
 ** @param {string} endTime - in format HH:mm
 ** @param {Date} date - date to compare, default is now
 ** @returns {boolean}
 */
function inTime2(startTime, endTime, date) {
  function toMins(v) {
    v = v.split(':');
    return v[0] * 60 + +v[1];
  }
  // ms since midnight
  var ms  = new Date() - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return ms >= toMins(startTime)*6e4 && ms <= toMins(endTime)*6e4;
}

console.log('Is it between 6am and 8pm? ' + inTime2('6:00', '20:00'));
```